# XSLT: how to check if a subelement is equal to a value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to select all Message objects with subelement messageType='PrimaryMessage'.

I tried to do this via

```xml
<xsl:pattern matching="/">
<xsl:for-each select="...">
```

But I haven't been able to achieve the desired result yet. Can anyone help me?

Example XML:

```xml
<S:Envelope
    xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <QueryResultList>
            <QueryResult>
                <Message xsi:type="ResponseMessageType"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <messageType>StatusMessage</messageType>
                </Message>
            </QueryResult>
            <QueryResult>
                <Message xsi:type="ResponseMessageType"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <messageType>StatusMessage</messageType>
                </Message>
            </QueryResult>
            <QueryResult>
                <Message xsi:type="ResponseMessageType"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <messageType>PrimaryMessage</messageType>
                </Message>
            </QueryResult>
        </QueryResultList>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: I suggest you first do a xslt intro like I.e. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="QueryResultList/QueryResult/Message[messageType='PrimaryMessage']"/>
```

Basicly you add a filter to your expath expression. So instead of doing a for-each over all Message elements we only want Message elements where the child element messageType equals 'PrimaryMessage'